# Prove that if $C$ is anti hermitian matrix then $\forall v\in \mathbb C^n \ : \ Re(\langle Cv, v \rangle)=0 $.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

Suppose $C \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb C)$ satisfies $C+C^* = 0$.

Prove that $\forall v\in \mathbb C^n \ : \ Re(\langle Cv, v \rangle)=0 $.

Here is what I was able to show so far:

We know that $C$ is anti hermitian matrix because $C$ satisfies $C^* = -C$. Also we know that each anti hermitian matrix is normal.

Thus we can define $d$ as eigenvalue of $C$ associated to a certain eigenvector $v$. From the fact that $C$ is normal we know that $\overline d$ is the eigenvalue of $C^*$ associated to the same eigenvector $v$.

Then we get $(-C)v = (-d)v$ and $C^*v = (-C)v = \overline d v$ and from this we can deduce that $\overline dv = (-d)v$ which implies that $\overline d = -d$

Then we get $Re(d) = 0$.

So we get :
$$Re(\langle Cv, v \rangle)= Re(\langle dv, v \rangle) = d\times Re(\langle v, v \rangle) = 0$$

But how do we know that $Re(\langle v, v \rangle)=0 ?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $C^*=-C$ so

$$\langle Cv,v\rangle=\langle v,C^*v\rangle=-\langle v,Cv\rangle=-\overline{\langle Cv,v\rangle}\implies \operatorname{Re}{\langle Cv,v\rangle}=0$$

Comment: Why $-\langle v,Cv\rangle=-\overline{\langle Cv,v\rangle}$?

Comment: See the five propriety of the [Hermitian inner product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitianInnerProduct.html)

Comment: Amazing how you simplified it. I wasn't even in the right direction to prove it. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome.